# C# HtmlAgilityPack encoding problem when loads html

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8, html-agility-pack

I'm using HTMLAGILITYPACK to extract all of data from a HTML local page but still have problem with special characters ... look it: https://prnt.sc/p7xegw (I can't use ~,`,´,ç and others).

This is my code to call my HTML page:

```cs
System.IO.StreamReader myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:/Users/Dev-02/Desktop/Daniel/xml_project/schemaproject/portal.html");

string arquivohtml = myFile.ReadToEnd();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

doc.LoadHtml(arquivohtml);
```

**Is there a way to set my encoding while I'm calling my HTML page?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the encoding to the `StreamReader` constructor, which parses your file's bytes.

Comment: Are you asking how to pass parameters? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_ and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding